# Refine duplicate selection with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns 'text' and 'lang' and I need to extract the groups (unique) of 'text' values that have the same number N of languages.
For example:

For the following example dataframe:

```
text     lang
--------------
text_a   en
text_b   es
text_a   es
text_a   it
text_c   de
text_c   pt
text_d   no
...
```

I can extract the list of languages per unique text:

```
df.groupby('text').lang.apply(list)
```

and that gives me a result like this one:

```
text_a -> [es, en, it, fr]
text_b -> [es, it, de]
text_c -> [es, nl, it]
text_d -> [fr, no, de, pt]
```

Now, from this result, how can i filter all the texts that appear in the same N languages?
For example, for spanish and french the desired result would be all the rows from the initial dataframe where all seleted text values also have 'es' and 'fr' on the lang column.

```
text     lang
--------------
text_a   fr
text_b   es
text_a   es
text_b   es
text_b   fr
text_c   fr
text_d   es
...
```

The output contains all texts that have a row with 'es' and a row with 'fr' and only those two appear in the output. The isin() function will not work here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `df = df[df.lang.isin(['es','fr'])]` ?

Comment: No, the isin() function will return an 'or' selection. I need an 'and' returning both rows: the one with 'es' and the one with 'fr'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Approach 1

`Query` the dataframe to filter the rows where the corresponding language is one of `en`, `es`, then group the filtered dataframe on `text` and transform `lang` column using `nunique` to get the counts of unique values, now compare the count to length of the defined set to create a boolean mask

```
lang = {'en', 'es'}
df_lang = df.query('lang in @lang')
mask = df_lang.groupby('text')['lang'].transform('nunique').eq(len(lang))

df_lang[mask]
```

#### Approach 2

Query to filter the rows then `group` the frame by `text` and aggregate `lang` using `set`, now `map` the aggregate column using `set.issubset` to test the membership of given languages

```
lang = {'en', 'es'}
df_lang = df.query('lang in @lang')
mask = df_lang.groupby('text')['lang'].agg(set).map(lang.issubset)

df_lang[df_lang['text'].isin(mask[mask].index)]
```

Result for `{'en', 'es'}`

```
     text lang
0  text_a   en
2  text_a   es
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shubham. it has the same problem that the one provided by Anurag below: i only want the specified languages in the output (both of them). Let's see if this rephrase works: give me all the texts for BOTH spanish and french from the input dataframe

Comment: @FranCasadome The proposed approach here is exactly doing that.

Comment: No... I get extra languages other than the ones i specify.
In your example for 'en' and 'es' you also get 'it'

Comment: @FranCasadome Added another approach which should be more efficient.